# MySql Functions

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm quite new to MySql. I'm trying to create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetDefaultLangText(tableName VARCHAR(50), fieldName VARCHAR(50), primaryFieldName VARCHAR(50), langID INT(10), 
                defaultLangID INT(10), itemID INT(10), actValue VARCHAR(200)) RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN  
    DECLARE sqlString VARCHAR(200);
    SET sqlString = CONCAT(CONCAT('(SELECT ', fieldName, 
    CONCAT(' FROM ', tableName, ' WHERE LangID = ')), CONCAT(defaultLangID ,' AND ', 
    CONCAT(primaryFieldName, ' = ', CONCAT(itemID, ')', NULL))));

    RETURN IF(actValue = NULL OR (CHAR_LENGTH(actValue) = 0), sqlString, actValue);
END;
```

However this gives me a syntax error can anyone help please ? 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong since I followed the online documentation

Comment: The actual error returned would help.

Comment: I'm sure, the problem is, that it only tells me to consult the manual :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that will work if you use only ";" as a separator

The typical is this:

DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `mytest` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `mytest` () RETURNS INT
BEGIN

select ...... ;

insert ...... ;

END $$

DELIMITER ;

Comment: yep it worked thanks. Although Now I have a new error: "Error Code: 1418. This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)"